# placeholder image for QGraphicsView in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qgraphicsview

I often have UIs that use QGraphicsView. At ***run*** time, I can put all sorts of wonderful things in my scene. However at ***design*** time in Qt Designer(Creator), I'd like to have some sort of placeholder image shown to help me visualize what the UI will really look like.

I cannot find a property for setting some kind of background image. I tried various settings in the styleSheet property, but nothing displays, e.g.

```
QGraphicsView: {
    background-image: speedo.png;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you just use the wrong syntax:

```css
QGraphicsView {
    background-image: url("/path/to/your/image.png");
}
```

---

[QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) is a `QWidget`, so you can use the [Qt Style Sheets Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) to design your widget with the allowed properties

Comment: I cannot get a background image to display in Qt Designer either at design time or in preview mode using background-image in Windows. For path syntax, I've tried "file:///C:/Temp/speedo.png" and "C:/Temp/speedo.png". I've also tried adding my image as a resource file and using url(:/rc/speedo.png).

Comment: @bfris it works for me, Have you let the `':'` after `QGraphicsView` ?

Comment: Arghh! I found the problem. My QGraphicsView was too small and the corner corner of my image was white. This trick works to scale the image. But you cannot scale using `background-image`. You have to use `border-image`. This works: `QGraphicsView { border-image: url("C:/Temp/speedo.png") 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;} `